# One screen garbled with fractional scaling on Xorg with Ubuntu 20.10 on Nvidia after boot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display-resolution, 20.10

TLDR: One 1080p monitor at boot is garbled to near blackness, turning fractional scaling off, then back on fixes it. This is running on Xorg with Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 20.10. Would like to have it work on boot. Suggestions?

So I have a triple monitor setup with one monitor being 4K and the other two being 1080p. Because one monitor is 4K I need to scale it to 150% to be readable/similar DPI to the others. Since I have an Nvidia card and want to use CUDA, Wayland isn't a great option. Ubuntu 20.10's fractional scaling on Xorg works well except at boot. The two 1080p monitors are set to 100% scale and the 4K to 150%. One of the 1080p monitors will become a garbled near black mess on boot (you can just barely see the white cursor outline and some white elements). However when I turn off fractional scaling, then turn it back on then everything works fine until I reboot.

With Xorg fractional scaling it seems like it renders the 1080p screens at a way higher res and then scales down correct? Is this somehow related to it? Anybody know how I could fix it to not mess up at boot?